# How to check minor Node.js version in AWS Lambda and Elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, version

I'm relying on Node version 12.17.x to make use of a specific feature (AsyncLocalStorage) in Lambda and Elasticbeanstalk. But for some reason, the Node.js version does not seem to publicly available. Why do they think that platform "12.x" tells me the real Node version? I want to know the exact minor and patch version, or at least give some news about it...

I had to create a test lambda function that prints `process.version`, but surprisingly, platform 12.x still uses v12.16. When will they upgrade to the latest stable version that came out more than 2 weeks ago? Are they publishing those releases somewhere? Google tells me nothing useful.

The same applies to Elasticbeanstalk instances. Node v12.17 does not exist in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/*`

Comment: The question in the title you've answered yourself. As to AWS's release schedule for updated runtimes, that's something only their support can answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've just checked in our sentry and the current version is newer-v12.18.4 so you can safely use AsyncLocalStorage now on v12 lambdas.

But AWS should really show this in the lambda administration panel. The fact that this is not shown anywhere and we have to use console logs or third party tools to get this info is a very poor DX. [image]