# How do I get exact version numbers of NodeJS my AWS lambda currently supports?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

How do I get the exact versions of Node.js, e.g. `18.1.2` that I can run on AWS lambda? The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html) gives me `18.x` which is not very specific.

Comment: I guess you can print it in a lambda and see what's the version. My fear is that AWS might not push the latest version in all the lambda you run. You might see differences from lambda to lambda...

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62309700/how-to-check-minor-node-js-version-in-aws-lambda-and-elasticbeanstalk

Answer (score 1):

Seems like:

- AWS doesn't show node.js version in the UI, so you need to `console.log(process.version)`
- the version can change at any time, no one will notify you